# Docker container running tomcat - Could not connect jms running inside tomcat container

Tags: docker, jms, tomcat7

Ia m running tomcat container. And started jms manually with command ./standalone.sh.

My dockerfile looks like this

> ```
>  ADD dockerscript.sh /root/dockerscript.sh
>  RUN chmod +x /root/dockerscript.sh
>  RUN /root/dockerscript.sh run $DOCKER_HOST $DOCKER_PORT> 
>  # Start Tomcat
>  ENV JPDA_ADDRESS 8000
>
>  CMD ["catalina.sh","jpda","run"]
> ```

In docker.sh

> ```
> docker build --no-cache --build-arg DOCKER_HOST=$INPUT_HOST
> --build-arg DOCKER_PORT=$INPUT_PORT -t $IMAGE_NAME . docker run --name    
> $CONTAINER_NAME -d -p $INPUT_PORT:$INPUT_PORT -p
> $DEBUG_PORT:$DEBUG_PORT $IMAGE_NAME
> ```

But i am not able to connect to jms queue with this approach.

Will tomcat can connect jboss jms running inside the container.

Thanks,
Kusuma

Comment: Get inside the container and install `net-tools` then use `nestat -plnt` to check if the port 8000 is actually listening inside the container or not

Comment: ran netstat -plnt. I have not got any port info regarding port 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
/ #

Comment: How did you run it? You need to run the image first and then use `docker exec -it <cntainerid> command`

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by adding jms port while docker build -p